# Create sliding text animation in swiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I am trying to animate some number text in swiftUI. But cannot find the desire result yet! For easier understanding please see the image below...

[image]

So far here is my code:

```
struct AnimatedText: View {
    
  @State var showingText = "234"
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(showingText)
                .font(.title)
                .transition(.slide)

        }.padding(20)
        
      Button("Add Number") {
          withAnimation(.spring()) {
              showingText += String(Int.random(in: 0..<9))
          }
         
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This animation can be achieved by applying an offset to the text *without* animation, then a negative offset to the text *with* animation. The size of the offset is the width of the text. This can be found by doing all the presentation in an overlay and using a `GeometryReader` to measure the size of the text footprint.

To make it more re-usable, you could split off the animated text into a separate `View`:

```swift
struct AnimatedText: View {

    let text: String
    @State private var overlayOffset = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .hidden()
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    let w = proxy.size.width
                    Text(text)
                        .offset(x: w)
                        .offset(x: -overlayOffset)
                        .onAppear { overlayOffset = w }
                        .onChange(of: w) { oldVal, newVal in
                            if newVal > oldVal {
                                withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                                    overlayOffset = newVal
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is how it could then be used in your example:

```swift
VStack {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        AnimatedText(text: showingText)
            .font(.title)
    }
    .padding(20)

    Button("Add Number") {
        showingText += String(Int.random(in: 0..<9))
    }
}
```

For moving the groups of numbers up to the top row, `.matchedGeometryEffect` could be used. Here's an attempt to show it working, with an updated version of the example:

```swift
@State private var textChunks = [String]()
@State private var bottomText = "0"
@State private var counter = 0
@Namespace private var ns

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(".").hidden()
            ForEach(Array(textChunks.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, chunk in
                Text(chunk)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: offset, in: ns, isSource: true)
                    .hidden()
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: textChunks)

        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                ForEach(Array(textChunks.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, chunk in
                    Text(chunk)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: offset, in: ns, isSource: false)
                        .animation(.easeInOut, value: textChunks)
                }
                AnimatedText(text: bottomText)
                    .id(counter)
                    .transition(.asymmetric(
                        insertion: .opacity.animation(.easeInOut),
                        removal: .identity
                    ))
            }
            .font(.title)
        }

        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button("Move up") {
                textChunks.append(bottomText)
                counter += 1
                bottomText = "0"
            }
            Button("Add Number") {
                if bottomText == "0" {
                    bottomText = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<9))")
                } else {
                    bottomText += String("\(Int.random(in: 0..<9))")
                }
            }
            Button("Reset") {
                withAnimation { textChunks.removeAll() }
                counter += 1
                bottomText = "0"
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
    .padding(20)
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Lot of thanks for huge effort.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to separate each character into its own `Text` view. Then a transition of `.push(from: .trailing)` achieves the desired result:

```
@State var showingText = "234"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            let charArray = Array(showingText)
            ForEach(charArray.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                let char = String(charArray[i])
                Text(char)
                    .transition(.push(from: .trailing))
                
            }
            
        }.padding(20)
        
        Button("Add Number") {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                showingText += String(Int.random(in: 0..<9))
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```